# How to update data in multiple objects at the same time using same method in firebase?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nosql

I am working on a real-time stock market application and saving data in Firebase like,

Structure:

```
{
data:
 0: {product_price: 123}
 1: {product_price: 134}
 2: {product_price: 125}
 …
 3: {product_price: 129}
}
```

Now the challenge is:

For 100,000+ products, I have to use a random method to change the price of each product, every five seconds.
Then, I also need to save the replaced price to show the graphical analysis of product's price evolution.

I am using the following technologies:

- **AngularJS** (Frontend framework)
- **NodeJS**    (Backend framework)
- **Firebase**  (Database Service)

How can I update the price of all the products at the same time (every 5 seconds)?

Is there any module or event driven programming, by which I can update every product at the same time.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try using [underscorejs](http://underscorejs.org/#each) `_.each` and `_.where`

Answer (score 3):

First of all, as this request only concern changes in your database, only the backend of your applications should be involved. (NodeJS - Firebase)

Then, i would advise you to check if you have subscribe to the Inferno pricing plan (https://www.firebase.com/pricing.html).
Otherwise, you will uses all your allowance really fast. (1 request (minimum) every 5 seconds equals 17280 request per day).

Finally, every 5 seconds, you will store 100.000+ products data on your firebase database. As you said, you want to keep a trace of the previous data. So you don't want to erase them.
Stocking 100.000+ products (that represents several KB and maybe even MB) on a cloud, every 5 seconds seems like a very bad idea).

I would say your request is unrealistic.
Except if you provide a huge physical infrastucture for your server.